# How to use Application variable like ASP in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables

I want to count the click on the each part of homepage, but not by using database. I think DB will bring some overhead.

The ASP code is:

```
<script language="vbscript" runat="server">

Sub Application_OnStart
application("vartime")=""
application("users")=1
End Sub

</script>
```

Comment: In your ASP example, the counter will reset when you restart the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to a project that adds an `$_APP` global variable. http://www.leosingleton.com/projects/code/phpapp/

FYI, it uses a file to store the $_APP data, but it doesn't look like it's doing any file locking or merging of `$_APP` when writing it back to the file. For a high traffic site or if you have CPU intensive pages, this could cause data issues in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since PHP is stateless, you will have to write it to the hard drive some how.
you can write to a file by using, [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

or, you can user the $_SESSION variable.

but, if it gets complicated, you'll have to use database, complicated data should be in the database.
The database will handle the hard drive most likely better than you